# Linear Regression with one variable

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, linear-regression, gradient-descent

While implementing Gradient Descent Algorithm in linear regression, the prediction that my algorithm is making and the resulting regression line are coming as a wrong output. Could anyone please have a look at my implementation and help me out? Also, please guide me that how can I know what value of "learning rate" and "number of iterations" to choose in specific regression problem?

```
theta0 = 0                               #first parameter
theta1 = 0                               #second parameter
alpha = 0.001                             #learning rate (denoted by alpha)
num_of_iterations = 100                #total number of iterations performed by Gradient Descent
m = float(len(X))                         #total number of training examples

for i in range(num_of_iterations):
    y_predicted = theta0 + theta1 * X
    derivative_theta0 = (1/m) * sum(y_predicted - Y)
    derivative_theta1 = (1/m) * sum(X * (y_predicted - Y))
    temp0 = theta0 - alpha * derivative_theta0
    temp1 = theta1 - alpha * derivative_theta1
    theta0 = temp0
    theta1 = temp1
print(theta0, theta1)

y_predicted = theta0 + theta1 * X
plt.scatter(X,Y)
plt.plot(X, y_predicted, color = 'red')
plt.show()
```

[Resulting regression line about which I need some help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UzsW.jpg)

Comment: Overall, it looks correct.  You may want to plot your error vs training step; could be you need more steps or a larger alpha.

Comment: Questions like this are generally better placed in https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your learning rate is to high, I got it working by reducing the learning rate to alpha = 0.0001.

Comment: Could you please guide me with one more thing? How can I know when to use a larger learning rate (like 0.01 or 0.001) and a comparatively smaller one as used by you (like 0.0001) ?

Comment: As far as a know you have to try to see if the gradient descent will converge, there must be some rules of thumb, but I cannot recall one right now. You can try other methods with adaptive learning rates to updates the weights, such as RMSprop or Adam.